# EF and Initializing Navigation Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am a bit of confusion. I have following Entity Class for EF.

```
public class Identity
    {
        public Identity()
        {

        }
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
        public virtual ClientDetails ClientDetails { get; set; }

    }
```

I read in couple of places in StackOverFlow that it is not recommended to initialize navigation property (not collection) in the constructor.

Could someone help me understand why is this so ?

Thanks
Anu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation properties are populated by entity framework (at least when you use the Include() method to tell it to populate that object) when you retrieve an item. Under the cover, it will create a foreign key to the object you are navigating to. This can be seen inside of the generated migrations.

Any code in your constructor is effectively going to be ignored when entity framework retrieves the items from the database, as it will use reflection to instantiate the instance of the class (this process *requires* the default constructor, or it will throw a runtime exception), and then use reflection to set the values for the various properties using what it has retrieved from the database.

Comment: Thanks Chris, So wouldn't same apply to Collection ? Why is it that we need to initialize collection ? Isn't the framework using reflection to initialize it ?

Comment: I'm actually not sure what specifically about collections would be different. Are you able to provide a link to where you've been seeing these posts that differentiate between the two in terms of constructor logic? Unless it is just as simple as 'empty collections are better than null collections for the *rest* of your code'.